# Bypass "Tell me who you are" error in git

Tags: git, git-commit, git-config

Upon attempting to commit a repository, I get the error:

```
$ git commit

*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

git config --global user.email "you@example.com"

git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got '[output redacted]')
```

The obvious solution would be to run the `git config` options in the output, however I do not want to do that.

The computer in question doesn't belong to a specific person but is a shared computer. Therefore, each commit would be a different user.

How do I bypass this and set author to be per commit and not a global?

Comment: If you run `git config` without the `--global` option, you will set the author only for that specific clone.

Comment: @approxiblue What if multiple people are gonna add to the same clone?

Comment: Having  one clone for multiple committers is questionable practice anyway. Why do you want to do that?

Comment: The code is worked on as a team. The computer in question also belongs to the team an no one specifically, meaning anyone on the team can use it.

Answer (score 24):

Another option is to use the `-c` flag to pass config paramter to the current command.

In your case `git -c user.email="your@email.com" -c user.name="Your Name" commit ...`

The `-c` values override any other default values (set and unset parameters).  Note that all the `-c` options need to come before the command name `commit`.

Comment: This worked for be but I had to use the syntax `user.email="you@email.com"` and `user.name="Your Name"` (notice the = sign).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `--author` flag:

```
$ git commit --author="A U Thor <author@example.com>"
```

Comment: I heard author and committers are different things though?

Comment: This is what happens when config is one name and author is changed: http://i.imgur.com/d933jHh.png

Comment: Why is that an image? Yes, author and committer are different.

Comment: As of git 2.12.2, this fails if the default isn't set.